# Coq: Proof of list pair

Tags: coq, coqide

I have wrote this Inductive predicate and part of the proof for its (strong) specification:

```
Inductive SumPairs : (nat*nat) -> list (nat*nat) -> Prop :=
| sp_base : SumPairs (0,0) nil
| sp_step : forall (l0:list (nat*nat)) (n0 n1: nat) (y:(nat*nat)), SumPairs (n0,n1) l0 -> SumPairs ((n0+(fst y)),(n1+(snd y))) (cons y l0).

Theorem sumPairs_correct : forall (l:list (nat*nat)), { n: nat | SumPairs (n,n) l }.
Proof.
...
```

The thing is I don't think the theorem is correct because Coq doesn’t accept something like `{n0 n1: nat | ...}`. Is there a way to fix that or am I thinking wrong?

I think the predicate `SumPairs` is correct, but since I'm not sure, here's an example of how it should work: input `[(1,2),(3,4)]`, expected output `[3,7]`

Comment: Hi Cris. Don't you expect, as "output", [(4,6)]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a pair in the result, e.g.:

```
Inductive SumPairs : (nat*nat) -> list (nat*nat) -> Prop :=
| sp_base : SumPairs (0,0) nil
| sp_step : forall (l0:list (nat*nat)) (n0 n1: nat) (y:(nat*nat)), SumPairs (n0,n1) l0 -> SumPairs ((n0+(fst y)),(n1+(snd y))) (cons y l0).

Theorem sumPairs_correct : forall (l:list (nat*nat)), { p: nat * nat | SumPairs p l }.
Proof.
intros l.
induction l as [|p l [[x y] IH]].
- exists (0, 0); constructor.
- now exists (x + fst p, y + snd p); constructor.
Qed.
```

However, for this particular task, it is actually better to just use a plain functional program:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Definition sum_list l := fold_left Nat.add l 0.

Definition sum_pairs l := (sum_list (map fst l), sum_list (map snd l)).
```

This definition is easier to read, to understand and to modify than the first version. Note that you can still use Coq to reason about the function:

```
Lemma sum_list_cat l1 l2 : 
  sum_pairs (l1 ++ l2) = 
  (fst (sum_pairs l1) + fst (sum_pairs l2),
   snd (sum_pairs l1) + snd (sum_pairs l2)).
(* Exercise! *)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! The only reason I didn't define it as a plain functional program is because my teacher didn't want to, but I'm gonna save it anyway. Thanks again!